# How can I prevent sublime text from unindenting after closing a block comment?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

If I have some JavaScript code that I want to comment out like:

```
{
    // Inside some scope
    var foo = "bar";
    foo += "bar";
}
```

I expect to have the following after commenting out the code

```
{
    /*
    // Inside some scope
    var foo = "bar";
    foo += "bar";
    */
}
```

But, instead I'll get something like the following, which I have to reindent:

```
{
    /*
    // Inside some scope
    var foo = "bar";
    foo += "bar";
*/
}
```

I want to know if there's a preference to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlight the code you want to comment out, and press `ctrl + /` - this will comment out the code without any indenting issues and is is easily reversible.  The other advantage of this strategy is it works across most languages (including HTML).

Alternatively, you could use `ctrl + shift + /` to use multiline comments, as rlemon mentions in the comments. (usually I'm too lazy)

Comment: +1 also - `ctrl + shift + /` for multi-line blocks in JS (`/**/` vs `//`)

Comment: @rlemon I think he's already doing that... He doesn't say how he's indenting, and if he was doing it by hand then he would simply indent it. He wants this feature to work properly. He probly has one of the ~4 indent settings wrong

Comment: Ohh, yea sorry I didn't read the question just Kittens answer. Felt I would add some info.

Comment: FWIW I'm using a Mac, so `cmd + alt + /` does the equivalent. BUT, this doesn't do what I want either, because `/*` AND `*/` will be at the start of the lines, regardless of scope (since they're on their own line).

Comment: @SomeKittens after 2 years, I changed my habits and now use `cmd + /` all the time :(